# Pre-installed applications

Tags: android, apk

Please help me, I'm trying  to find some documentation about pre-installed applications at Android. 
I need to know what does it means, what permissions it has and how can I  "pre-install"
my app for testing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does it means

It means applications that ship as part of the firmware build on a device.

> what permissions it has

A pre-installed app has no special permissions simply by being pre-installed. An app installed on the firmware can hold `signatureOrSystem` permissions that otherwise would be unavailable (e.g., `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`).

> how can I "pre-install" my app for testing

You would have to build your own firmware. Light testing might be achieved by rooting your device and putting your app in the spot where pre-installed apps live (`/system/app` IIRC), but since most consumer devices are not rooted, your tests may be flawed.